# Java for loop needs to pick up where it left off

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, methods

I need the second for loop to pick up where it left off. Every time the `if` statement is `true` I need a slot to fill in the array used in the first `for` loop. But I don't want the same key value to keep getting added. I need the second `for` loop to move to the next key value. (In the code below, `arrl` is an ArrayList of objects that have a value)

```
int temp = 0;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < eeVal.length; i++)
{
    count= 0;
    for(int j = temp; j < arrl.size(); j++)
    {
        if(arrl.get(j).getValue() == 1 && count == 0)
        {
            eeVal[i] = arrl.get(j);
            count++;
            temp=j;
        }
    }
}
}
return eeVal;
```

Comment: Why dont you add one to j? `j++`

Comment: I don't know where it will leave off @Thrasher

Comment: Please clarify what you're doing. You have an array and 2 lists, 2 indexes... Are arrl and arr the same size? What's the purpose of this?

Comment: typo I fixed it

Comment: If I am correct, you want to add all items from arr1 to eeVal which meets the condition that getValue is 1? Also, what is the size of eeVal?

Comment: Are you searching for the `continue` keyword?

Comment: I only want to add the objects with the key value. in the code there it is 1

Comment: What's the purpose of the outer loop?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the array `eeVal` is used as the destination, or would it be OK to collect the objects to a new array? There are clean ways to do this in java 8.

Comment: I have to have them put into eeVal

Comment: As of now it is filling in the spots in eeVal with the same value

Answer (score 2):

You need another variable to track where the inside loop has gotten to. Something like the following:

```
int temp = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < eeVal.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = temp; j < arrl.size(); j++)
    {
        if(arrl.get(j).getValue() == 1)
        {
            eeVal[i] = arrl.get(j);
        }
      temp=j;
    }
}
}
return eeVal;
```

This way, once the outside loop runs the second time around, the inside loop will start from 'temp' until the end of the loop.

Comment: I hope I understood your question correctly... you might need to also change eeVal[temp] = arrl.get(j) as well so you can store the right index.

Comment: You did. I updated the code in my original question because it is still not working

Comment: Try changing eeVal[i] to eeVal[temp]

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, it sounds like you do not want the inner `for` loop. The traversal of `arrl` needs to be manually controlled using a variable, e.g.`cnt', which only gets incremented when your condition for incrementing it is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably are looking for is a `List`.

In your answer, you don't need the first loop. This one has issues though - index `i` can go out of bounds.

```
int i = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < arrl.size(); j++) {
    if(arrl.get(j).getValue() == 1) {
        eeVal[i++] = arrl.get(j);
    } 
} 
return eeVal;
```

What you need is a dynamic collections such as List.
Using list (I am calling the type as MyType).

```
List<MyType> vals = new ArrayList<>();
for(MyType item : arrl) {
    if(item.getValue() == 1) {
        vals.add(arrl.get(j));
    } 
} 
return vals.toArray(new MyType[vals.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was picking up where the last correct value was. I needed to add 1 to j when I wanted progress to know where I left off.

```
int count2 = 0;
int progress = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < retVal[h].length; i++)
{
    count2 = 0;
    for(int j = progress; j < arr.size(); j++)
    {
        if(arr.get(j).getLevel() == h && count2==0)
        {
            retVal[h][i] = arr.get(j);
            count2++;
            progress = j+1;
        }
    }
}
return retVal;
```